# Security risks on given session infrastructure

Tags: session-management

I want to know if this is a suitable schema for session management. Once the user has authenticated with user/pass, the server returns `session = MD5(SECRET + user_id)` (along with other fields) where `SECRET` is a random string (say 256 bits).

Then the client just sends the received `session` hash with every request, and the server validates it by checking that `MD5(SECRET + user_id)` equals the received hash.

What are the potential risks here? I guess that if the user is able to send an empty `user_id` then she is a step closer to `SECRET`, but this is easily avoidable. Plus, `SECRET` could chage every week or so.

(Note: I'm using Node as the backend for a mobile app, so there's no browser and no cookies).

Comment: This protocol has several weaknesses. You would be better off if you would use a new and unique random string as session cookie for each successful login and store it together with the user id for an appropriate time on the sever.

Comment: The safe way is to hexify 256 bit secret and use just that. Then lookup on the server-side who this secret belongs to. The secret can be changed every time users logs in, it's not bad idea to not keep it the same.

Comment: @aventurin The problem with your solution is that I need to run a db query for every message. Anyway I'd like to know the weaknesses of my protocol.

Comment: You could probably use a fast key value store, e.g. Redis.

Comment: But this secret should be different for each user. This way you still need to lookup secret in database to see to which user it belongs. You can introduce caching of it so it's not in the database.

Comment: In case you want to keep it this way you can switch to SHA-256 and then it will be safer over SSL.

Answer (score 1):

**Length Extension Attack**

What you have is basically a MAC to verify your `user_id` value. The problem is that a primitive MAC like `MAC = md5(KEY | MESSAGE)` is vulnerable to [length extension attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack).

This means that an attacker with the user id `1` could for example impersonate a user with the id `10` by just appending a `0`.

At a minimum, you would need to use a proper [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) or use a non-vulnerable hash function such as sha3.

**Token Expiration**

If you store no state on the server, you have the problem of not being able to revoke a token.

So if a user for example changes their password because they suspect a compromise, an attacker that gained a token beforehand can still use it. You have no way of invalidating it, and need to wait until it expires naturally.

**Solutions**

What you seem to be looking for are [client side sessions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)#Client_side_web_sessions). You may want to consider using existing solutions such as [JWT](https://jwt.io/#libraries-io) or some other [existing library](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/12/using-secure-client-side-sessions-to-build-simple-and-scalable-node-js-applications-a-node-js-holiday-season-part-3/).

**Further Problems**

As @0x23212f said, your scheme obviously does not replace TLS and will not protect you from man in the middle attacks.

Aside from that, you should consider if you actually need client side sessions. If - as you suggested in the comments - the only reason is to avoid one database query, it's probably not worth the trouble implementing it, or the additional network overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean apart from MiTM (Man in The Middle) attacks?

Because that would be the most obvious to see here. If you are sending the same hash with every request, that means there is a possibility that an attacker can intercept the request and use it to *spoof* the user.

If you want to avoid that too, you might wish to take a look at DUKPT (Derived Unique Key Per Transaction). Banks use a proprietary version of DUKPT as far as I know.

But then again, I wouldn't really go that far. A secure communication channel would help prevent the aforementioned issue.